# How does a loaded die affect this probability

Tags: probability

> Suppose I own five different six-sided dice. Four of the dice are fair dice
>   and they are equally likely show the values $1, 2, 3, 4, 5,$ and $6$.
>   
>  
>   One of the dice is loaded and never shows
>   the values $1, 2,$ and $3$ but is equally likely to show the values $4,5$, and $6$.
>   
>  
>  
>   Suppose I randomly pick one of the five dice and then roll it twice.
>   What is the probability I pick the loaded dice and see two sixes?

I am unsure about how the loaded die affects the equation.
So far I have I have:

$P(L) =$ probability of picking up a loaded die

$P(S) =  $probability of rolling 2 sixes on the loaded die

$$P(L) = \frac {1}{5}$$
$$P(S) = \frac {1}{3} \times \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{9}$$

So should I just multiply  $$P(S) \times  P(L)$$

If so, how does the loaded die affects the outcome?

Comment: With the wording as it is now, your approach is correct; the answer is $1/5 \times 1/9 = 1/45$.  Incidentally, it is also the case that the probability that you choose a fair die and roll two $6$'s is $1/45 = 4/5 \times 1/36$.  So the probability of rolling two $6$'s is $2/45$.

Comment: To answer your other question, the loaded die affected the outcome because rolling two $6$'s is not independent of which die you choose.   $P(\text{roll two $6$'s} \mid \text{loaded die}) = 1/9$, as you observed, but $P(\text{roll two $6$'s} \mid \text{fair die}) = 1/36$,

Comment: Oh I see. Since they do not equal each other, they are independent.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "they", but no, the two events *are* dependent.  It's just that you calculated the probabilities using the formula $P(A, B) = P(B) P(A \mid B)$, with $A = \text{roll two $6$'s}$ and $B = \text{loaded die}$.  That formula holds whether $A$ and $B$ are independent, or dependent as they are here.

Comment: ok. I understand now.  I misread your previous note.